# (Parse SDK) includeKey on Array of Pointers, Don't retrieve objects and returns an empty Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

i have the following class`Places` which includes array of pointers for a class called Ratings,

when i do the following
`PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"place"];` the ratings array is being returned as pointers according to parse documentation

> By default, when fetching an object, related PFObjects are not fetched. These objects’ values cannot be retrieved until they have been fetched

adding the following line which is working for me for pointers only not arrays `[query includeKey:@"ratings"];` the ratings array is being returned as empty array

It seems the only way to fetch the actual objects is to run something like this:

`NSArray * ratings = [firstPlaceObject objectForKey:@"ratings"];
PFObject *firstRating = [ratings objectAtIndex:0];
firstRating.fetch;`

or

`NSArray * ratings = [firstPlaceObject objectForKey:@"ratings"];
[PFObject fetchAllIfNeeded(ratings)];`
which for sure isn't the optimal solution

is there is other way to fetch all the ratings once or a better way to achieve it.

[Parse Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44UlM.png)

Comment: I think you should use PFRelation instead of array of pointers.